# In need of spiral

Tags: vector

Could someone tell me how to create a fibonacci spiral substituting the actual line with a string of 1s and 0s?

I have tried AutoCad but can't seem to figure out how to replace the line with numbers.

Comment: What application do you intend to use?

Comment: I don't have a specific one. I am not any kind of graphic designer. I was hoping this would reach someone who could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator:

Assuming you can create the spiral line (=quarter circles) a few cuts, you can simply replace normal solid stroke. Create a pattern brush that have 1 and 0.

[image]

The binary string can be whatever. The numbers can be rotated. Convert the characters to outlines to allow free geometric manipulation.

**Other options:**

Illustrator can place also text along a path. It's better than the brush method, if it's important to keep individual characters undistorted. The brush method distorts characters if the curve has steep curvature.

Inkscape has path effect "Pattern along a path"

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have AutoCAD use AutoCAD. Just draw the spiral, either approximate it or user a autolisp script to raw the curve. Then use something like the autolisp script [curvetext](http://www.cadstudio.cz/en/download.asp?file=CurveText) to type the text needed on your path.

[image]

**Image 1**: Quick test with quickly spline approximated fibonachi spiral. One can fit the curves better this is more of a proof of concept.

Or you can do this in ilustrator or inkscape if you wish.